java.lang.NoSuchMethodException in Python Flink JDBC
I am trying to read data from Kafka and sink data to Postgresql with Flink streamingAPI using Python. I am using Flink version 1.19.1 and Postgresql 14.13. Here is my code
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaOffsetsInitializer, KafkaSource
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowDeserializationSchema
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment, FlatMapFunction, RuntimeContext
from pyflink.common import WatermarkStrategy
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.jdbc import JdbcSink, JdbcConnectionOptions, JdbcExecutionOptions
from pyflink.datastream.state import ValueStateDescriptor

class CountWindowAverage(FlatMapFunction):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = None

    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        descriptor = ValueStateDescriptor(
            "average",
            Types.TUPLE([Types.INT(), Types.INT()])
        )
        self.sum = runtime_context.get_state(descriptor)

    def flat_map(self, value):
        current_sum = self.sum.value()
        if current_sum is None:
            current_sum = (0, 0)

        current_sum = (current_sum[0] + 1, current_sum[1] + value[3])

        self.sum.update(current_sum)

        if current_sum[0] >= 2:
            self.sum.clear()
            yield (value[0], current_sum[0], current_sum[1])

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_parallelism(1)
env.set_python_executable("/home/mhtuan/anaconda3/envs/flink-env/bin/python")
env.add_jars("file:///home/mhtuan/work/flink_kafka/flink_sql_kafka.jar", "file:///home/mhtuan/work/flink_kafka/flink-connector-jdbc-3.2.0-1.19.jar", "file:///home/mhtuan/work/flink_kafka/postgresql-42.7.3.jar")

deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(
                             type_info=Types.ROW_NAMED(
                             ["id", "hour_key", "name", "age"], [Types.INT(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])).build()

source = KafkaSource.builder() \
    .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9091,localhost:9092,localhost:9093") \
    .set_topics("test-flink-3") \
    .set_group_id("flink-1") \
    .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
    .set_value_only_deserializer(deserialization_schema) \
    .build()

ds = env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")
ds = ds.key_by(lambda record: record["id"], key_type=Types.INT()).flat_map(CountWindowAverage())

ds.add_sink(JdbcSink.sink(
        "insert into flink.flatmap_age (id, count, sum) values (?, ?, ?)",
        Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.INT(), Types.INT()]),
        JdbcConnectionOptions.JdbcConnectionOptionsBuilder()
            .with_url('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres')
            .with_driver_name('org.postgresql.Driver')
            .with_user_name('postgres')
            .with_password('postgres')
            .build(),
        JdbcExecutionOptions.builder()
            .with_batch_interval_ms(1000)
            .with_batch_size(200)
            .with_max_retries(5)
            .build()
    ))

env.execute("kafka_sink_example")

Everything works fine
When running the code, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mhtuan/work/flink_kafka/./src/main.py", line 102, in <module>
    ds.add_sink(JdbcSink.sink(
  File "/home/mhtuan/work/flink-1.19.1/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/datastream/connectors/jdbc.py", line 60, in sink
  File "/home/mhtuan/work/flink-1.19.1/opt/python/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/home/mhtuan/work/flink-1.19.1/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
  File "/home/mhtuan/work/flink-1.19.1/opt/python/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o174.getDeclaredMethod.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.JdbcOutputFormat.createRowJdbcStatementBuilder([I)

Does anybody know how to fix it? Many thanks!
